# Where to put Resource folder and files in .NET Clean Architecture for Globalization and Localization?

Tags: asp.net-core, globalization, clean-architecture, onion-architecture, asp.net-core-localization

Where should I put my Resource folder in .NET Clean Architecture for Globalization and Localization? I have the following layers

1 - Domain
2 - Application
3 - Infrastructure
4 - WebApp

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the Globalization and Localization should put inside the view's layer. Normally, it will be inside the WebApp. Since the Globalization and Localization this is related with showing the page with different language.

Answer (score 0):

I think its better have it in the first option (Domain Layers) and have it available for all the project. I do this because of the need of have internationalize message in the other layers and they are part of the domain of the solution

Comment: Then, we need to add reference of the domain to each layer, Doesn't it the wrong approach?